# Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am developing app with inapp billing. I received this error on some of my devices:

> Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.PurchaseParams

I looked for any good solution but I didn't find one. Do you have any working solutions? In my app I used code from [the Google official example for billings](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing).